# Issue with header for Microsoft SQL server report builder

Tags: reporting-services

For our site we have a logo on the top left, their address box on the top right, a horizontal line to separate the header from the body. As of now the logo is static but my task is to change out the logo depending on a value from SQL. I was able to get that to work by conditionally showing and it looks great in the report building tool.

The issue is when I view the PDF, it bumps the line seperating the body from the header higher on the page so that it cuts into the address box. I remove the condition so that nothing disappears and then it looks good again.

From my testing it seems to bump up the line (and the first row of text depending on report) up when something conditionally disappears thinking it needs to move up to fill the gap but not caring there is other stuff there.

Comment: Try placing the horizontal line within a rectangle.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! A coworker also suggested that but through the application I had a tough time telling when it was in the box and when it was just merely laying on top of it.

Comment: One of the many _joys_ of SSRS... An easy way to tell if the line is within the rectangle or on the rectangle is to simply make it wider than the current rectangle, if it resizes the rectangle then you know it is inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

When you go into Preview in your report. Click the button that says PRINT LAYOUT next to the printer icon. Here you can change how the report looks when it is exported. Note this is only a preview.

Once you have changed the dimensions of the page/ layout/ paper type, you can go back to the design mode,  right-click outside of the box and click report properties. Set the paper sizes to what you changed in Preview.

Now, go back to preview and check how the report looks. You may need to play with your margins, column sizes, headers and footers to make sure everything fits correctly.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks! More of the issue was things shifting up. I ended up just taking the things that shifted up and shift them back down. At this time we have two images that toggle show or hidden and they are the same height. If that changes I will need to figure out how to get it into the box correctly.